# Assignment operator keyboard shortcut for R session in (q)terminal

Tags: r, linux, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Lubuntu 22.04 with Qterminal. When starting an `R` console session in the terminal, I would like to have a shortcut such as `Alt+=` for `<-`. How might I do this?

I know how to do this in R-studio with an actual R-notebook (`.Rmd`) since one can simply modify the keyboard shortcuts; however, if I just want to quickly prototype something or check the outputs of some simple logic, I prefer to just use the terminal with a console session.